# What happened to Goku's "Dragon Balls"?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In the Dragon Ball Z: Super Android 13! movie, when Goku is fighting with Super Android 13, there is a [scene that showed](http://youtu.be/zYP4nNMLn9E?t=6s) Super Android 13 punching Goku in the dragon.. uhmm... genitals.

**Caution:** This picture can cause unexpected pain in the crotch!
[Watch it at your own risk.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9RJB.jpg)

Is there any evidence that Goku managed to produce Goten before that fight?
Because I have a doubt about whether he could use *them* ever again.
Are the two circles in the picture (that appear to be torn apart) something else?

Comment: I came here from the main page, and was wondering if the Q was about genitals... seems the hunch was right. But puns aside, is there any source proving that these were really his genitals pictured?

Comment: He likely couldn't use them anymore. But this happened in a completely different timeline not canon to the anime or manga so it has no effect on the main story

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the vast possibility of Goku eating a sensu bean after that, we can assume he regrew anything that was damaged. We also know that Goku is an alien. Although he looks human, he might not have balls there. Or balls at all. But if he does, like young Goku sometimes shown, he doesn't really use them that much :D

Comment: you are mistaken. in the original dragon ball when goku was still young his genitals were shown many times :P